# SVG Translate Path object with a user defined coordinate system

Tags: php, svg

I have a simple path definition (just an example) that I want to be able to translate with accuracy on the svg canvas.

```
M 30.872704,198.53891 C -143.04429,-148.7562 503.71813,57.927231 257.70273,102.67753
```

What I want to do is set the origin (top left corner) of the path to the origin of the svg document (top left corner) by using transform="translate(0,0)" on the path object. Basically I want to set the path in the top left corner so I can then apply further translations to it in relation to the svg document.

I want to avoid using any javascript to do this if possible.

My thoughts are I can return the bounding box of the path by using php to exec Inkscape and use the commandline option --query-all. I could then calculate the distance from the path to the document origin and reset it.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A bezier curve never extends outside of the quadrilateral formed by it's endpoints and control points.  The same is obviously true of straight lines also.  Therefore you can get an excellent approximation to the bounding box of the path by just parsing all the points and keeping track of the min and max values of the X and Y coordinates.

The resulting bounding box will sometimes be slightly bigger that the real bounding box of the path, but it may well be close enough for your needs.

Parsing the path with a small PHP script is probably going to be easier and faster than invoking Inkscape.